# Find the base view controller name

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiviewcontroller

I searched for this on SO and other sites but didn't find anything useful

What I have is..
One base class say `TOPViewController.h/.m` 
In this class I have created my controls and I am using this class on all my other views, by creating object of this class.

Say,
`ViewController1`, `ViewController2`, `ViewController3` are my other views and I am using the `TOPViewController` on all these views.

Now My current view is `ViewController2` which is visible. I jumped from `ViewController1` to `ViewController2`.

now in my `TOPViewController` how I will come to know which is my current `viewcontroller` visible.

All the view controllers are adding TOPViewController object as `[self.view addSubview:topViewObj];`

Here is code of adding my TOPViewController in all views,

```
topBarViewObj = [[TopBarViewController alloc]init];
    topBarViewObj.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    topBarViewObj.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 50);
    topBarViewObj.titleLable.text = @"TEST";
    [self.view sendSubviewToBack:topBarViewObj.view];
    [self.view addSubview:topBarViewObj.view];
```

Please guide me for the same.
Thanks in advance..

Comment: Are you using a `UINavigationController`?

Comment: yes. I am using navigation controller

Comment: use this NSStringFromClass([self class])

Comment: If I use NSStringFromClass([self class]), it is returning me the name of TOPViewController, but I need the name of view on which TOPViewController is added

Comment: post some code please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to know which is the top most `UIViewController` visible according to your `UINavigationController` (so the last `UIViewController` that has been pushed on your `UINavigationController` stack):

```
self.navigationController.topViewController;
```

Comment: :- I tried this code in viewWillAppear of TOPViewController, it gives me <nil>

Comment: My guess is `self.navigationController` is nil. Do you have a public property for your `UINavigationController` in your `AppDelegate`? If so, you could try accessing that instead of `self.navigationController`

Comment: self.navigationController.topViewController; is working with me on my ViewController1, ViewController2, ViewController3... not in my TopBarViewController... I need to check in my TopBarViewController from which view it is called....

Answer (score 0):

if you are using UINavigationControoler

you can get baseViewController

```
baseViewControoer = [self.navigationController.viewControllers firstObject]
```

But if you did not use the following line

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController: animated:];
```

you will not get above result

Comment: I need to find in my TOPViewController, it gives me null

Comment: Do u want to find which is top view in your topViewController ? are your views are UIViews? or are they viewControllers?

Comment: @iAnurag :- I have added my topViewController on all views, by the same code posted above. I want to find which is the current view on which my topViewController is added. I am having topViewController object, I want to get the parent of topViewController

Answer (score 0):

as you are adding TopBarViewController's view with addSubView to your view so you just try to get the parent class by calling

```
`id parentClass = [self.view parentViewController]; ` 
and then try with 
`if([parentClass isKindOfClass[ViewController1 Class]]){ 
// view 1 
}
else if ([parentClass isKindOfClass[ViewController2 Class]])
{
  // view 2
}
else if ([parentClass isKindOfClass[ViewController3 Class]])
{
  // view 3
}
`
```

It might work for you. Let me know.